# AFNetworking hit a breakpoint in AFAutoPurgingImageCache unexpectedly

Tags: ios, multithreading, debugging, memory, block

I came across a weird issue after adding AFNetworking to my iOS project. The version of AF is `3.2.1`. If I add a breakpoint at `line 111` in `AFAutoPurgingImageCache.m` and then run this project, this breakpoint will weirdly be hit. However, if I move this breakpoint to line 110 or line 112,  it won't be hit anymore. May anyone tell me why it was hit? class `AFAutoPurgingImageCache` is only used when downloading images, which has no business with the request I have sent.

The method that contains this special line is

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

I have made a screen snapshot of the position of the breakpoint.
[image: the weird breakpoint]

Here is the stack when the breakpoint is hit.

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
Thread 2 Queue : com.apple.NSURLSession-work (serial)
Thread 3 Queue : requestHeaderModificationQueue (concurrent)
#0  0x000000010df0d740 in __destroy_helper_block_e8_32s40s48s at /.../Pods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/AFAutoPurgingImageCache.m:111
#1  0x00007fff51a759ba in _Block_release ()
#2  0x000000010dfa9e8e in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#3  0x000000010dfba2a0 in _dispatch_lane_concurrent_drain ()
#4  0x000000010dfb134c in _dispatch_lane_invoke ()
#5  0x000000010dfac0ff in _dispatch_queue_override_invoke ()
#6  0x000000010dfbb399 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#7  0x000000010dfbbca6 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#8  0x00007fff51c089f7 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#9  0x00007fff51c07b77 in start_wqthread ()
Thread 4Thread 5com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread (6)Thread 7Thread 8Thread 9
```

The codes using AF are just a few lines written in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    static AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = nil;
    manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
    
    id<AFURLResponseSerialization> responseSerialization = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = responseSerialization;
    
    [manager GET:@"https://www.google.com/" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }];
    
    return YES;
}
```